# no implicit conversion of nil into String in html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

The following is one of my many mailer templates:

```
<% if @system_email.present? && @system_email.try(:content).present? %>
  <%= @system_email.content.to_s.gsub(
  "::vUserName::", @wanted_equipment.try(:name) ).gsub(
  "::iListingId::", @equipment.identifier).gsub(
  "::vListingTitle::", @equipment.title).gsub(
  "::vCategoryName::", @equipment.try(:category).try(:name)).gsub(
  "::eListingType::", @equipment.listing_type ).gsub(
  "::SYSTEM_COMPANY_NAME::", @system_company_name).gsub(
  "::SITE_LISTING_URL::", link_to(@system_site_url, equipment_details_url(@equipment.slug))).html_safe
  %>
```

**ApplicationMailer**

```
def newequip_matches_wanted
    @system_email = SystemEmail.find_by(title: 'Equipment matches WantedEquipment')
    @subject = @system_email.try(:subject).to_s
    @subject = "Equipment matches WantedEquipment" if @subject.blank?
    @equipment = Equipment.last
end
```

While trying to render this html.erb template it's throwing an error  saying:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
Extracted source (around line #2):

<% if @system_email.present? && @system_email.try(:content).present? %>
  <%= @system_email.content.to_s.gsub(..
```

I am adding the email.content just to show considering a comment:

```
@system_email = SystemEmail.find_by(title: 'Equipment matches WantedEquipment')



 => #<SystemEmail id: 28, identifier: "MAIL-0000028", title: "Equipment matches WantedEquipment", subject: "Equipment matches WantedEquipment", content: "<p>Hello <strong>::vUserName::</strong>,</p>\r\n    ...", footer: nil, status: 1, created_at: "2017-03-01 07:36:30", updated_at: "2017-03-01 07:40:07">
```

The same template works with other mailers. But it is throwing an error here. Could somebody tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: it does not find the :content

Comment: There is content in that particular system_email. I'll edit the question with more resource.

Comment: `@wanted_equipment.try(:name).to_s` just do this for each second parameter of gsub.

Comment: Actually I created a whole new template since I didn't have much time. But I'll try your solution and let you know @Omkar

Answer (score 1):

It says **implicit conversion**, explicit exists:

```
2.3.1 :001 > nil.to_s
 => ""
```

So you don't have any of these: identifier, title, listing_type, slug in @equipment, @system_site_url or @system_company_name.
I also don't know if you really wanted to use @equipment.title or use the email's title.

It is a bit odd method but you can try out. Redefine NilClass's to_s method and add to_s to every field. It will then pop out what you missed.

```
class NilClass
  def to_s; "NILNILNIL"; end
end
...
2.3.1 :010 > nil.to_s
 => "NILNILNIL"
```

Comment: I edited the question with more resource. Could you please tell me what am I missing? There is :identifier, title and everything under that system_email.

Comment: Updated the answer. My guess is that you wanted to use `@system_email.title` instead of `@equipment.title`.

Comment: @user3576036 Have you found the problem?

Comment: I did want to use `@equipment.title`. I was running outta time. So I created whole new template, fetching plain data from @equipment variable.  This is working.